# change php's time zone to server's time zone

Tags: php

I guess the title says everything . Is there a way in my php script I can change php's timezone to server's time zone so that strtotime() and SQL's UNIX_TIMESTAMP will return the same result ?

Comment: Hey, i should the PHP timezone is the Server's timezone man. If you want to set a new timezone, try date_default_timezone_set: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Hey, saying server you meant ubuntu..But I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the date_default_timezone_set function to set the desired time-zone. Alternatively you can set the date.timezone = "Your desired value" in the php.ini file if you can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the time zone configuration in your php.ini to;

```
date.timezone = UTC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP function--

> date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier );

You can get the value of $timezone_identifier from below--

```
    'Kwajalein' => -12.00
    'Pacific/Midway' => -11.00,
    'Pacific/Honolulu' => -10.00,
    'America/Anchorage' => -9.00,
    'America/Los_Angeles' => -8.00,
    'America/Denver' => -7.00,
    'America/Tegucigalpa' => -6.00,
    'America/New_York' => -5.00,
    'America/Caracas' => -4.30,
    'America/Halifax' => -4.00,
    'America/St_Johns' => -3.30,
    'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' => -3.00,
    'America/Sao_Paulo' => -3.00,
    'Atlantic/South_Georgia' => -2.00,
    'Atlantic/Azores' => -1.00,
    'Europe/Dublin' => 0,
    'Europe/Belgrade' => 1.00,
    'Europe/Minsk' => 2.00,
    'Asia/Kuwait' => 3.00,
    'Asia/Tehran' => 3.30,
    'Asia/Muscat' => 4.00,
    'Asia/Yekaterinburg' => 5.00,
    'Asia/Kolkata' => 5.30,
    'Asia/Katmandu' => 5.45,
    'Asia/Dhaka' => 6.00,
    'Asia/Rangoon' => 6.30,
    'Asia/Krasnoyarsk' => 7.00,
    'Asia/Brunei' => 8.00,
    'Asia/Seoul' => 9.00,
    'Australia/Darwin' => 9.30,
    'Australia/Canberra' => 10.00,
    'Asia/Magadan' => 11.00,
    'Pacific/Fiji' => 12.00,
    'Pacific/Tongatapu' => 13.00
```

Comment: This will not answer the question : he knows how to set the timezone but don't know how to set the timezone specifically of his MySQL server.